# How to get reference by reactTag?

Tags: react-native

How to get reference by reactTag?

We can get the current reactTag through the findNodeHandle method. By passing in a parameter, this parameter is reference
e.g.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { findNodeHandle, View } from 'react-native';
...

export default App extends Component {

    componentDidMount () {
        const myTag = findNodeHandle(this.refs.myComponent);
        console.log('myTag', myTag); // myTag 111(must be a number)
    }

    render () {
        return <View ref='myComponent'></View>
    }

}
```

When I trigger (Component of the blur event, I can pass (. TextInputState. CurrentlyFocusedField () access to the current focus is acquired reactTag. I want to find the corresponding reference through the reactTag, how can I do?

Comment: i think you need to do it like this :  const myTag = findNodeHandle(this.refs["myComponent"];